# Firebase NodeJS Authentication Login Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, socket.io, firebase-authentication

i have managed to make a login system and accounts and everything. Only one issue.

When I login in through one device and I open the website up on another, it is logged in with the account. Hence, my website is only allowed to be logged into one account on every device. I saw that there were a couple of forums on this, but they were really old and didn't really have a solution. 
Is there any way in solving this problem? I'm using the createToken and verifyToken but not sure if I am doing it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: DIsclaimer: haven't played a lot with firebase auth.
I'm assuming that's the issue. Because every time you create a new token, firebase is invalidating the previous token.

Comment: So then how do i create multiple tokens for multiple users; isn't this what I need to get varying users to login?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"